# I have golang error while putting struct into slice

Tags: go

Full code:

```
   package main

    import (
        "net"
    )

    var arrayOfConnections []*Connection

    type Connection struct {
        conn net.Conn
        id   int
    }

    func main() {
        serv, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
        defer serv.Close()
        connectionHandle(serv)
    }
    func connectionHandle(serv net.Listener) {
        conn, _ := serv.Accept()
        arrayOfConnections = append(&Connection{conn, 1}, 0)
        conn.Write([]byte("one"))
        conn.Close()
    }
```

have an error:

> first argument to append must be slice; have *Connection

error in this part of code:

> arrayOfConnections = append(**&Connection{conn, 1}**, 0)

I'm new to Golang and it is really hard to figure out what am I doing wrong. How to rewrite the code so the new connection will be finally append to the slice? Couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow. Hope someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices and https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15 for documentation and examples. If you're just starting, you should probably run through the Tour of Go from start to finish at least once.

Comment: The erroneous line of code appears to be trying to append the integer `0` to a pointer to a `Connection` struct. As the error says, you can only append to slices. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I want to put every new net.connection to a slice array. How to rewrite the code to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The append should be like this

```
arrayOfConnections = append(arrayOfConnections, &Connection{conn, 1})
```

The append builtin function follows the signature

```
func append(s []T, vs ...T) []T
```

When s is the slice you want to append and vs are the elements you want to append to s, and then de function returns a new slice with all the elements appended.

Comment: Now It's obviously what was wrong. I don't know why, but when you learn Go first time it's so hard to see that kinda mistakes. Thank you very much!!!!